# Pyside perform action only once

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have two buttons that I have connected via signal slot like so

```
self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.someFunc)
self.button_2.clicked.connect(self.someFunc2)
```

no every time I click on the button_1, button_2 their functions are performed.  The buttons are in a button group so only one can be checked at a time, the problem I am having is that the function runs every time I press the button, but I want that function to be run only once.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your function, put an if statement checking to see if it has been ran or not.

```
firstRun = true
def someFunc:
    if not(self.firstRun):
       return
    # doSomeFunc
    self.firstRun = false
```

Or at the top of the function, you could disconnect the connection.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#disconnect-4

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late for this question, but if anyone else has this issue, an alternative suggestion is to disable the button via the setDisabled(True) method after it has been run. This prevents it from being activated AND gives the user feedback that they cannot run it again.

ie `self.button_1.setDisabled(True)` somewhere in the body of the function.